# How do i check if a variable is set or not in Less like Sass's variable_exists($name)

Tags: less

I am trying to convert Sass to Less but I got problem. In Sass code there are [`variable_exists($name)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#variable_exists-instance_method) but Less does not have similar function. So I converted code below

**Sass**

```
.test {
    background: if(variable-exists(background), $small-font-size, red);
}
```

↓

**Less**

```
.define-test(@background: red) {
    background: @background;
}

.test {
    .define-test(); 
}
```

It works but I got problem if it will be complicated code. Please tell me how to convert complicated Sass code in Less below:

**Sass**

```
.test {
    font: if(variable-exists(font-size), $font-size, 100%)/#{if(variable-exists(line-height), $line-height, 1.5)};
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same model as your Less example. Like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.font(%40size%3A%20100%25%3B%20%40lh%3A%201.5)%7B%5Cn%20%20font%3A%20%40size%20~%5C%22%2F%5C%22%20%40lh%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.font()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.test2%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.font(12px%3B%202)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D). There is no alternate that I am aware of. Less doesn't have the exact equivalent of that `variable-exists` function.

Comment: @Harry Thank you replay. I got it.

Comment: @Harry There're some but it's actually *two* features in one: `is-defined` function and a `ternary operator` function.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'll answer - because it turns out to be a perfect example to illustrate what's wrong with all those conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't:

While it's possible to convert this code line-by-line (using some hints from [#1894](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1894) and [#1400](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1400)), like this for example:

```less
// defaults:
@font-size:   none;
@line-height: none;

// styles:
.test {
   .-(@s,   @h) {@size: @s; @height: @h}
   .-(none, @h) {@size: @s}
   .-(@s, none) {@height: @h}
   .-(@font-size, @line-height);
   font: @font-size/@line-height;
}

// user/custom overrides (comment/uncomment to test):
@font-size:   33px;
@line-height: 5.55;
```

[Demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20defaults%3A%5Cn%40font-size%3A%20%20%20none%3B%5Cn%40line-height%3A%20none%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20styles%3A%5Cn.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20.-(%40s%2C%20%20%20%40h)%20%7B%40size%3A%20%40s%3B%20%40height%3A%20%40h%7D%5Cn%20%20%20.-(none%2C%20%40h)%20%7B%40size%3A%20%40s%7D%5Cn%20%20%20.-(%40s%2C%20none)%20%7B%40height%3A%20%40h%7D%5Cn%20%20%20.-(%40font-size%2C%20%40line-height)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20font%3A%20%40font-size%2F%40line-height%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20user%2Fcustom%20overrides%20(comment%2Funcomment%20to%20test)%3A%5Cn%40font-size%3A%20%20%2033px%3B%5Cn%40line-height%3A%205.55%3B%5Cn%22%7D).

---

#### Do:

You actually *don't* need any of above conditionals at all if you go a declarative way. The right Less code for that stuff is as simple as this:

```less
// defaults:
@font-size:   100%;
@line-height: 1.5;

// styles:
.test {
   font: @font-size/@line-height;
}

// user/custom overrides (comment/uncomment to test):
@font-size:   33px;
@line-height: 5.55;
```

[Demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20defaults%3A%5Cn%40font-size%3A%20%20%20100%25%3B%5Cn%40line-height%3A%201.5%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20styles%3A%5Cn.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20font%3A%20%40font-size%2F%40line-height%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20user%2Fcustom%20overrides%20(comment%2Funcomment%20to%20test)%3A%5Cn%40font-size%3A%20%20%2033px%3B%5Cn%40line-height%3A%205.55%3B%5Cn%22%7D).

---

Note that neither of these "config" variables have to be global. You can use namespaced variables to override both global defaults (like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20global%20defaults%3A%5Cn%40font-size%3A%20%20%20100%25%3B%5Cn%40line-height%3A%201.5%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20styles%3A%5Cn%23some-very-specific-style%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.theme(some-very-specific-style)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20font%3A%20%40font-size%2F%40line-height%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20custom%20overrides%20for%20very%20%23some-very-specific-style%5Cn.theme(some-very-specific-style)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40font-size%3A%20%20%2033px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%40line-height%3A%205.55%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)) or also namespaced defaults (like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20defaults%20for%20very%20%23some-very-specific-style%5Cn.theme(some-very-specific-style)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40font-size%3A%20%20%20100%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40line-height%3A%201.5%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20styles%3A%5Cn%23some-very-specific-style%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.theme(some-very-specific-style)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20font%3A%20%40font-size%2F%40line-height%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20custom%20overrides%20for%20very%20%23some-very-specific-style%5Cn.theme(some-very-specific-style)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%40font-size%3A%20%20%2033px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40line-height%3A%205.55%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)), and so on.